# Multiple Paths for img and css in CakePHP 3.4

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am running multiple cake apps which share one core/baseapp.

The basic structure is:
www/myapp1
www/myapp2
www/myapp3
www/baseapp

In each 'myapp' inside app.php I point the path for templates and plugins to the myapp and baseapp so that if no file is found in myapp the one from baseapp is used:

```
'App' => [
        'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
        'paths' => [
            'plugins' => [ROOT.DS .'modules'.DS, BASEROOT . DS . 'modules' . DS],
            'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS, BASEROOT.'/src/Template'.DS ],
        ],
    ],
```

(i include classes from baseapp inside composer.json which is probably not relevant for this question)

That works pretty well.

Question:
How can I make it include img, css and js in the same manner? 
I want to have to folders where cake should search for the files for every app.

```
'App' => [ 'imageBaseUrl' => ['img/', BASEROOT. DS . 'webroot/img/']
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution: In the folder webroot I made a link to BASEROOT (with the name 'baseroot') and then I made the File src/View/UrlHelper

```
class UrlHelper extends CakeUrlHelper{
    public function webroot($file){
        //code
        if (file_exists(\Cake\Core\Configure::read('App.wwwRoot') . $file)) {       
            $webPath = $this->request->getAttribute('webroot') . $asset[0];
        }else{
           $webPath = $this->request->getAttribute('webroot').'baseroot'.DS.$asset[0];
        }
        //more code
    }
}
```